Cannot install blender 4 on M2 Mac, Sonoma
I download a Mac dmg file from this link:
https://www.blender.org/download
It says Blender 4.3.2 for macOS - Apple Sillicon. I have a new M2 Macbook Air 2022. The file is named blender-4.3.2-macos-arm64.dmg
When I try to open the .dmg file my MAC gives back an error:

Translated it says: "The connected Medium couldn´t be read by this computer." Then there are three options: reject, ignore, initialise. The ignoring options is not doing anything. The initialising leads to the hard disk utility.
Tried the same with the Intel x64 version for good measure with the same result.
Any ideas?

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.
